# Why is the nextPageToken not in returned response from google endpoint?

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I am using Google App Engine which works fine returning records back from my list endpoint. I have been reading

```
    http://ido-green.appspot.com/CloudEndpoints/CloudEndpointsWebBlogPost.html
```

which says that when we specify a value for limit parameter a value for nextPageToken will be returned . For example:

```
    % curl http://localhost:8888/_ah/api/birra/v1/beer?limit=1
    {
      "items" : [ {
"id" : 1,
"beerName" : "bud",
"kindOfBeer" : null,
"score" : null,
"numberOfDrinks" : null,
"image" : null,
"country" : null,
"description" : null,
"latitude" : null,
"longitude" : null
} ],
      "nextPageToken" : "E-ABAIICF2oJbm9fYXBwX2lkcgoLEgRCZWVyGAEMFA"
    }
```

But when I execute my endpoint "nextPageToken" does not appear, although I know there are other records to be returned. It was actually working before and has now stopped working. My Endpoint code is the same as it was before.

Is there something I am missing or not doing? I am using app engine SDK 1.9.0 . I running app engine through eclipse and accessing the endpoints using url

```
  http://localhost:8888/_ah/api/explorer
```

in chrome.

Comment: The nextPageToken is returned only when there are more items available. Are you sure it is the case ? You can check by going to http://localhost:8888/_ah/admin . Second, you tagged your question with google-cloud-sql. Are you using Google Cloud SQL or the Datastore ?